# Mui v5 Theme Palette typescript override not working

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to override one of the colors in the `mui` palette in my typescript project. I created a `createPalette.d.ts` file with the following:

```
import type { PaletteOptions, Palette } from '@mui/material/styles';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  export interface PaletteOptions {
    grey: SimplePaletteColorOptions;
  }
  export interface Palette {
    grey: PaletteColor;
  }
}

declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  export interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    grey: true;
  }
}
```

I then create my theme like this:

```
import type { PaletteOptions } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const palette: PaletteOptions = {
  grey: {
    main: '#fff',
    dark: '#fff',
    light: '#fff',
    contrastText: '#fff',
  },
};
```

However, I get the following error:

> Type '{ main: string; dark: string; light: string; contrastText:
> string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial'.   Object
> literal may only specify known properties, and 'main' does not exist
> in type 'Partial'.

For some reason it's not using my override type. Does anyone know how to fix this so it uses my interface definition? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `PaletteColorOptions` as the type in both `export interface PaletteOptions` and `export interface Palette`?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @MarksCode? I'm facing the exact same problem